# How to extract the url from a website when the url gets abbreviated in the chrome console?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup Python Question:

Hello all, webscraping beginner here! I am trying to extract the url of an element on a specific website. I click inspect, and it only shows the abbreviated version of the url on the Chrome inspect element area. If it's shorter, the link will show in full. When I click the url on the html on Chrome's inspect element area, it takes me to the desired link on Chrome.

When I try to extract it as an a.['href'] it only returns the abbreviated link. (Fake example: 'https://pizza.com/pepperonis/mozzarella/../onions'.)

You can see how the fake link above has those dots and it gives me an error when I  the   which doesn't work when I try to use it in my python program.

Anyone encountered this and can help?

I tried to use a f string and it didn't work to estimate what the string would be.

Comment: add simplified code that represent problem

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Why not just copy it from the address bar after clicking on it if it *"takes [you] to the desired link"*?</sub>

If you mean [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUlAx.jpg), then **after clicking on the element** (in dev tools),

1. go to the "Properties" tab (it should be to a side or at the bottom) and then
2. right click on the `href` property and
3. select "Copy string contents"

OR:

1. right click on the `href` attribute [in the "Elements" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPJbh.png) itself and
2. click on "Edit attribute" and it should automatically [select the whole link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGGRE.png), and
3. then you can either `CTRL`+`C` or right-click and select "Copy".

---

> I tried to use a f string and it didn't work to estimate what the string would be.

That's not [how f-strings are meant to be used](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#simple-syntax) - they do not [and cannot] estimate unknown entities - you have to specify pre-existing variables to fill them.